# Parse yaml file with varying number of key:values

Tags: bash, yaml, sh, yq

Long story short, I will be parsing yaml files in a directory with bash using yq. My yaml files could look like this:

```
CLIENT_FIRST_NAME: bob
CLIENT_LAST_NAME: smith
```

Or

```
CLIENT_FIRST_NAME: bob
CLIENT_LAST_NAME: smith
CLIENT_MIDDLE_NAME: michael
```

So I am looping through each file with a do loop and setting the variables to values
For example:

```
for f in $FILES
do
  FIRSTNAME=$(yq r $f CLIENT_FIRST_NAME)
  LASTNAME=$(yq r $f CLIENT_LAST_NAME)
add client --firstname=${FIRSTNAME} --lastname=${LASTNAME}
done
```

But sometimes I will have that middle name and I would need to include that:

```
add client --firstname=${FIRSTNAME} --lastname=${LASTNAME} --middlename=${MIDDLENAME}
```

The order doesn't matter, I just need to be able to account for additional fields that may show up in the yaml that need to be added to the 'add client' command. EVERY line in the yaml will be added to the command.  Every key added will be a viable parameter for the 'add client' command. I don't have to worry about whether or not a key in the yaml is a valid parameter. They WILL be.

Curious on the best approach to the unknown here. Thanks!

Comment: `for f in $FILES` is already a serious problem. You can't safely store a *list* of files in a *string* variable. Remember, filenames can have spaces, newlines, glob characters, etc; and expanding `$FILES` is running through string-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: BTW, what version of `yq` is this that treats `r` as a subcommand? Don't you mean `-r`?

Comment: I am using the latest version of yq: 3.3.0.  It uses 'r' in the README as a valid subcommand and has worked so far.

Comment: ahh, we're using two completely different programs named `yq`. The one my answer was written and tested against is version 2.8.1 of the one from https://github.com/kislyuk/yq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming yq returns nothing if it doesn't find a key.

I might make the entire flag based on whether yq returns something, like

```sh
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  FIRSTNAME=$(yq r "$f" CLIENT_FIRST_NAME)
  MIDDLENAME=$(yq r "$f" CLIENT_MIDDLE_NAME)
  LASTNAME=$(yq r "$f" CLIENT_LAST_NAME)

  [[ -n $MIDDLENAME ]] && MIDDLENAME="--middlename=${MIDDLENAME}"
add client --firstname="${FIRSTNAME}" --lastname="${LASTNAME}" "${MIDDLENAME}"
done
```

Comment: This is missing quotes -- consider running it through http://shellcheck.net/. And it just doesn't work at all for the same reason the OP's code doesn't -- `yq` doesn't take `r` as a subcommand. (There's an `-r` option, which I _assume_ is what the OP meant).

Comment: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/read seems to imply the 'r' is valid, without the hypen. I'll give that a shot though, just spitballing here.

Comment: Huh. We're using two completely unrelated tools both shipped under the `yq` name, the one I'm familiar with (and was testing against) is https://github.com/kislyuk/yq

Answer (score 1):

This code would be far more efficient if you only ran `yq` *once per input file*, not once per data item per input file. Consider:

```
for f in *.yml; do
  { read -r firstname; read -r middlename; read -r lastname; } < <(
    yq -r '(.CLIENT_FIRST_NAME, .CLIENT_MIDDLE_NAME // "", .CLIENT_LAST_NAME)' "$f"
  )
  add client \
    --firstname="$firstname" \
    ${middlename:+--middlename="$middlename"} \
    --lastname="$lastname"
done
```

Some notes to use in reading this:

- Each `read` command in bash reads one line, when `-d` is not used to modify this.
- The above `yq` command *outputs* one line per data item.
- Using `// ""` causes the empty string, instead of `null`, to be used when no `CLIENT_MIDDLE_NAME` is found.
- `${foo:+...words here...}` expands to `...words here...` if-and-only-if `foo` is set to a non-empty value.

Comment: What do the slashes following the .CLIENT_MIDDLE_NAME do here?  I like how this is indeed more efficient, appreciate it.

Comment: That's basically a short-circuiting "or" (vs a normal jq/yq "or", which has output as a boolean). Without that, a YAML file without any middle name at all would put `null` in the output at that location.